# wrong convert date() PHP

Tags: php, date, time

I used date() to convert 12H time to 24H using this code

```
$over = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2021-12-16 13:42:46 PM"));
echo $over;
```

but the output is this below:

```
1969-12-31 16:00:00
```

How to get rid of this, is this a bug? or my code?

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d0a5225626dd7dac916c12bdcb4ab34b9b552b08)

Comment: You've added PM with time: 13:42:46. It's not allowed

Answer (score 3):

13:42:46 PM isn't 12h time format (PM is nonsense in 24h format), 01:42:46 PM is correct.

Comment: Yes, strtotime() returns bool(false) with 13:42:46 PM.

Comment: @jspit; according to OP, it returns `-28800` here. Any idea why?

Comment: strtotime returns false. Due to its time zone, date does not return 1970-01-01. try self https://3v4l.org/DUXM7

Comment: this is so true! thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just specify the correct date format (`PM` is not supported):

```
$over = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2021-12-16 13:42:46"));
echo $over;
```

Which date format is supported you can find in https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.php

Comment: AM/PM is supported, but is nonsense if you pass 24h time format.